# Imported third party module does not have __file__ attribute

Tags: python, python-2.7

## Background

I have done some research on how the `__file__` attribute works from the [docs (scroll down to 'modules')](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy), and various websites.

From what I understand, all python modules should have a `__file__` attribute as long as long as it was loaded from a file.

## The Issue

I am installing the third party python module `opencafe` using

```
(env)$ pip install opencafe
```

I am utilizing this test framework.

The issue occurs when I run the test command from the CLI. When that command is run, it triggers this file: `env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cafe/configurator/managers.py`.

Within that file there is

```
import cafe
```

and later on

```
_PLUGIN_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(cafe.__file__), 'plugins')
```

When this file is run, this error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

The same error occurs in this scenario:

```
(env) $ pip install opencafe
Collecting opencafe
  Using cached opencafe-0.3.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: opencafe
Successfully installed opencafe-0.3.1
(env) $ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 18:31:42)
>>> import cafe
>>> cafe.__file__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__file__'
```

## My Thoughts

My natural inclination is to just believe that this is an issue with `opencafe` itself, since I am only installing the framework and running a test command from CLI.

However, I wonder if there is an issue with the installation into a virtual environment, or perhaps the PYTHONPATH.

The docs say clearly that "The `__file__` attribute is not present for C modules that are statically linked into the interpreter". This module is a python module installed locally. It is not linked to the interpreter like the `sys` module.

[EDIT]

Here is some more good information about namespace packages.

http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000393/ch10.html#_discussion_172

> The main way that you can tell if a package is serving as a namespace package is to check its `__file__` attribute. If it’s missing altogether, the package is a namespace.

## Final Update

It turns out that `opencafe` does not work with the newest versions of `virtualenv`. It only works at version `15.0.1` or earlier. Reverting back got rid of this error message for me.

When it installed with this version, a `__init__.pyc` file was created in the package within the virtualenv. This byte compilation is how the `__file__` gets its information.

Answer (score 4):

That's because `opencafe` is not a normal python-module. You can easily see this when you open their main module [`__init__`](https://github.com/openstack/opencafe/blob/master/cafe/__init__.py#L19).

The `declare_namespace` explicitly creates a `namespace` package. For more informations about this you can visit [PEP-382](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0382/).

Comment: Thank you. I was not familiar with namespace packages. That being the case, would you say that the issue is indeed with opencafe itself, since it calls `cafe.__file__` within one of its own modules? Is there any work around besides manipulating that line with every install?

Comment: Note that PEP 382 was rejected.

Comment: @user2357112 That's correct but I was thinking about the section "Namespace packages today".

Answer (score 1):

It's a namespace package, a weird kind of package that can be split across multiple directories. It's not supposed to have a `__file__`, due to this splitting mechanism.

Comment: That being the case, would you say that the issue is indeed with opencafe itself, since it calls cafe.__file__ within one of its own modules? Is there any work around besides manipulating that line with every install?

Comment: @gliemezis: It does? Weird. I don't think it should be doing that.

Comment: Yeah [right here](https://github.com/openstack/opencafe/blob/master/cafe/configurator/managers.py#L613). I agree it is weird. It is not a recent change, but is now causing this error for me.

Comment: It turns out that OpenCafe has not been updated to work with newer versions of python and more specifically, the most recent versions of `virtualenv`. Installing `opencafe` with an earlier version of `virtualenv`, specifically `15.0.1`, allowed the install got rid of this error.